# How to check if a variable is present in a list (from txt), then logically printing it out

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to match a variable (three at a time in the future) to a list. The list is from a txt document with dates. The variable is the current day.

I'm new to python but i found plenty of SO threads about what i tought was the problem. I didn't store the code, but I have no idea what i might have done right/wrong.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
date = now.day
date = float(date)
oldDate = date - 3  # 25 at the time of testing
oldDate = float(oldDate)
# li = [23, 24, 25, 26, 27] what stuff.txt is like

with open('stuff.txt', 'rt') as f:
    lines = f.read()
    print(lines)
    if lines[2] == oldDate:
        print(1)
    else:
        print(0)
```

Right now it prints 0, but I can't figure out why i can get 1

Comment: Think about what the type of `lines[2]` is, and what the type of `oldDate` is.

Comment: how can i check the type of lines[2]?  I konw oldDate is float.

Comment: `print(type(lines[2]))`.

Comment: ahh i see, its a string

Comment: you can try to force lines[2] to also be a float by changing it to float(lines[2]) like you do for float(oldDate)

Comment: What did you think it would be instead? What does `f.read()` return?

Comment: @ineedhelp Yes, and two objects of different types will never be equal (except for objects like numbers and objects with custom equality overloads). You need to convert it to a float like you did above

Comment: Guys how could i make the whole list into numbers with the type float? (int will work too i guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
lines = open(stuff.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
for line in lines:
   if line == thevariable:
      print("found")
   else:
      print("not found)
```

Try this, it'll read & remove all \n, and then it'll read line by line checking, adjust it to your own needs.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `oldDate = float(oldDate)` do this `oldDate = str(oldDate)`
This way you are converting the date into a string and the file reader gives by default a string it should work.

Good luck